# Velocity ui not working on Wordpress (wrong enqueue maybe?)

Tags: wordpress, velocity.js

I'm trying to get velocity ui working on my wordpress installation with the starter foundation theme JointWp (http://jointswp.com/) but isn't it. So far I enqueue successfully velocity.js using following this tutorial:

(http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321)

but velocity ui isn't working. At the moment I have this 3 lines:

1) wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js', array(), '2.1.0', false );

2) wp_enqueue_script( 'velocity', get_template_directory_uri() . '/foundation/js/vendor/velocity.min.js', array(), false );

3) wp_enqueue_script( 'velocity-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/foundation/js/vendor/velocity.ui.min.js', array('velocity'), false );

1) The first line is jquery enqueue by default (works nice),

2) I enqueue velocity.js (works nice too),

3) Didn't show any error but don't load velocity ui because animation never happen. I tried without include the dependency to velocity, changing the name from "velocity-ui" to "velocity" as in the second line, and a lot of crazy things and nothing happen.

So... Someone have any idea about how I can accomplish this?
As I told you if you can help me a bit I will appreciated, because I tried to find a solution on the web and there is nothing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the position of your libs by changing the false option to true.